# How to create and insert data into the table in Magento 2

Tags: magento2.2

enter code here i am creating a custom extension to save the data in database but all the time getting . only one error

{"0":"Class data_example does not exist","1":"#0 D:\xampp\htdocs\store\vendor\magento\framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader.php(19): ReflectionClass->__construct('data_example')\n#1

data_exampe is my table name and i set it in Model\ResourceModel

her is my extension file code

app/code/Well/Done/Model/DataExample.php


`class DataExample extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel{

    public function _construct(){

        $this->_init("Well\Done\Model\ResourceModel\DataExample");

    }

}
?>`
app/code/Well/Done/Model/ResourceModel/DataExample.php


`class DataExample extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel{

    public function _construct(){

        $this->_init("data_example","id");

    }

} 
?>`

Comment: Post your whole extension code to your question

Comment: Have you made any dataprovider?